# how to record the time of app in background when I user Gestures Password in android

Tags: android

I use gestures password in my project,I want to achieve a demand,the app is running, when i  open other app, i want to record the time my app in the background of the time , if the time  is greater than three minute, than show the gestures password activity ,so ,how do I record this time.

Answer (score 0):

Use AlarmManager. Simply show your activity when it is triggered.

```
AlarmManager  alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Date date= new Date();
long timer = date.getTime()+(60*1000*3);
Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(ACTION );
alarmManager.set(
                    AlarmManager. RTC_WAKEUP,
                    timer,
                    PendingIntent. getBroadcast(context ,1,  intentAlarm , PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT ));
  }
```

And in your broadcast receiver simply start your activity

```
 @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast. makeText(context, "AUTO DISCONNECTION", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        context.unregisterReceiver( this);
        context.startActivity( new Intent(context,
                    YourActivity. class));

  }
```